# Running Program from Remote Share - Does it run in RAM - Is it ok to do?

Tags: windows, memory, smb, remote-execution

In this specific case, I have a folder called "games" which is all emulators.

I used to have 2 separate PC's, so I had this folder synced with my FileServer, but now that I use a VM on the same PC, I wondered if I could launch the emulators from the FileServer without losing performance.

I don't mind if it takes a moment longer to load, just that it runs as fast as it should. My guess is that it would load the Program completely into the RAM, so it should be fine.

I'm trying to not double backup files on the same machine, no need to have 2 copies.

Some of the programs are portable, as in the exe file and all needed files are on the remote share, some are like dolphin, were the program is installed on my computer, but the "config" dir is on the remote share.

I don't want to confuse anybody, this may not help, but my VM is ontop of an ESXi hypervisor, as well as the separate VM for the FS. So they are on the same Tower, but running in totally different containers/VM's.

Edit: If you have time, here is a demo video of my VMWare VM, its got a dedicated GPU and resides on the same host as the FileServer.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yNpIo_g02gM&t=221s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I can say that I have run GTAV and some other games from network shares just fine. Loadup time is def impacted, but games seem to run fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vSphere view client, it is a remote connection to the virtual machine.  In this case you have access to the whole CPU and disk IO, but will be limited in terms of graphical performance.  You can't fit 1920x1080x60 hz/fps through even gigabit.  If you have VMWare workstation, and store the VM on a remote server your disk IO will be limited to your network performance.

As long as you have an emulated video card, graphical performance will be lower than if each VM had it own GPU.

Comment: This is why I figured It would just confuse people regarding VM. This question is about will the program run in RAM completely basically. I am not using any of the things you've described above. I have a dedicated GPU for this VM.

Comment: If you are simply storing the VM files on your file server, then you will only have reduced disk IO.  However, if you have gigabit networking then the reduction usually isn't noticeable.  Like any computer it will use all the RAM you assign it plus disk IO to fetch new files from the image.  The physical files remain on the file server, but use network IO when you need to read/write to them.

Comment: All the files reside on the same tower so I'm not sure network I/O is a factor. I think I read that ESXi knows when network traffic is destined for an internal VM and the packets never leave the host.

Comment: I just linked a youtube video to my setup if you have a moment, basically those games I'm running are on an attached VM disk, I'd like to just launch them thru a file share, but only loose loading time, not in game performance. I also don't mind if there is a slight save lag. Just not during actual gaming.

Comment: running dolphin on  the host, and storing the files on a file share shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Yea but I've also got like N64, which is a portable program, which I could run from the host. And a few other "portable" Emulators. Most are portable except dolphin, which I agree, should be ok, since the actual Program resides on the Host.

Comment: Even if the N64 is on a file share all the important parts are loaded into RAM.  I hope you have a RAID or SSD since you are running so many VM.